# C# using accessors to change class' properties

Tags: c#, properties, get, set, accessor

I was wondering the following question as i cannot check into it myself at this time.

Say i have a class A which embeds another (private) class B with a (private) field B_F.
I made the B class private so i can change it via the property accessors to add additional algorithms before actually returning/assigning the value.
There is also the same kind of logic for field B_F in B - the field is private and uses an accessor.
The question is: if i do this A.B.B_F = new_value, will it also trigger the "set" accessor in the A class for the embedded class B?

Comment: Why don't you *show* us some sample code rather than just describing it? It's a very confusing description, but I'm sure with actual code it would be simple to understand - and you could also test this yourself, trivially, as far as I can see... you say you "cannot check into it" yourself - why not? It should take about 5 minutes with a compiler and text editor. If you're not near a compiler or text editor, then it's not going to actually affect you at the moment, is it? Wait until you *can* check it yourself.

Comment: Coming back to this 7 years later, I'm really sorry I didn't put much more required effort into this question. Sorry! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if i do this A.B.B_F = new_value, will it also trigger the "set" accessor in the A class for the embedded class B?

No. You will only do that when you assign a value to `A.B` directly, not for any of its child properties.